# Magento - Retrieve order products with a specific custom option

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I want to retrieve all product IDs that has a specific (custom) option value (provided by the customer in the frontend) from all orders - regardless of store/website.

The option is a text field (`Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option_Type_Text`), the SKU (and title) is **test_option** and the value I'm looking for is **green**.

I would prefer to do this with a raw MySQL query, but a solution using Magentos models/collections would definitely suffice.

Comment: I did find the `product_options` field in the `sales_flat_order_item` table. However it appears to be JSON-encoded, which would make it difficult (and inefficient) to filter out with a simple MySQL query.

Answer (score 0):

try with below code

```
<?php $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection'); 
$productIds = array();
foreach($collection as $order) {
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order->getId());
    $items = $order->getAllItems();
    foreach ($items as $item){
        $proOptions = $item->getProductOptions();
        if($proOptions['options']){
            $productIds[] = $item->getProductId();
        }
    }
}
?>
```

$productIds variable returns all product ids  which has a specific (custom) option value.

May it helps you !

Answer (score 0):

For direct sql query you can try this. If you want to put some condition, you can add according to your requirement.

```
SELECT sfoi.product_id FROM sales_flat_order e 
LEFT JOIN 
sales_flat_order_item sfoi 
ON 
( e.entity_id = sfoi.order_id )
```